# Unity on my android device does not connect to mysql server

Tags: android, mysql, unity-game-engine

I have a mysql server hosted on a dedicated hosting server. When using the play button in unity, everything works and the game is able to interact with the mysql server. When I try to build and run on my android device, The android device is not able to connect with the mysql server. When I used Nox as an emulator on my PC and run my APK it was able to connect to the mysql server.

Also just to note: I do have the "internet access" set to required in the player settings. Any help is welcome! Thanks

Comment: Is there any firewalls on your sql server or an ip whitelist?

Comment: have you set grant to everything for that user within mysql? normally people put in a web page and get the data from there so that there is an element of data protection

Comment: Some other things to check: is your device connected to wifi? Can you reach the server from a browser on your device? Also: check the Unity console window for messages when playing your app on your device to see where it's not working.

Comment: just checked, when i go to my php script that is hosted on my website on my android phone, the script does run and it shows the correct error code since I have not sent any username or password input

Comment: @BugFinder, yes the mysql user that I am using has full permissions to the mysql database

Comment: Ok, I have figured out the problem. When I build it as a gradle project it does not connect to the php scripts but when I build it as an internal project it does. Is there anyway to allow it to work while building it as a gradle project?